# how to escape curly braces in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

how do you escape curly braces in netbeans 8.0.2 every time that i press and "(" netbeans automatically inserts a ")" this is fine by me but i wanted to know if there's a way after i finish putting my text inside the braces to escape then and put my cursor at the end of the line (i know that i can press the end key) but that key is too far from my hands, in eclipse if you press enter you can do this, is there a command by default to do this in netbeans, or how can i map that when i press enter inside curly braces in short period my cursor will be set at the end of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution is `shift+;` just press shift and the semi colon key at the same time